# Unable to edit category data

Tags: category

Good evening all!

Firstly, I'd like to apologise if this question has already been asked, however, I couldn't find anything. Secondly, I'd like to say that I am new to Magento so, if I'm being stupid, please let me know!

Anyway.....In the 'Manage Categories' area of Magento I had previously assumed that clicking on a pre-existing category would load the category data into the form on the right for editing. However, I have two installs (one live, one local) that have exactly the same issue - the data is never shown - it merely reloads the 'New Root Category' page.

So, I looked at the ajax call that is being made when I click on the category and this does indeed return the 'New Root Category' HTML. The URL looks a little odd though?

http://magento.local/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/000141f111845c06b2618a0fcf04914c/?url=admin%2Fcatalog_category%2Findex%2Fkey%2F4b51ab928415eedcc6c96e59a750704aid/6/&isAjax=true

(I am using admin rewrites if you're wondering where index.php has gone.)

Local Machine:

Ubuntu 12.04
Nginx 1.1.9
PHP 5.5.14

Remote/Live Server:

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Nginx 1.4.6
PHP 5.5.9

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Regards

Comment: I would start by disabling all your custom modules and try again. It looks like something odd is preventing the category from loading.

Comment: @MayersDev Thank you for your response. At the moment, other than the admin rewrite (the problem also existed before I installed this), there are no custom modules - just the standard install.

Comment: @MayersDev Just wanted to let you know that I have resolved this. The problem was with my Nginx configuration (old config) and I didn't put two and two together (which I SHOULD have done with the url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue and, despite the fact that it was entirely my fault, I figured people might be able to learn (somehow) from my mistake.

So, as I stated before, this is my first time using Magento. Under normal circumstances I write bespoke systems and this project started out that way (before deadlines made this impossible). Anyway, the problem was caused by accidentally leaving my old nginx configuration active (The config for my bespoke systems). It didn't help that, other than this problem, this configuration didn't cause any issues; but that's beside the point. The offending line was:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /index.php?url=$1;
```

This should have been

```
rewrite / /index.php
```

I guess the moral of this story is, if you're experiencing a similar issue, go and check your server configuration is right! (Magento provide a default configuration for nginx here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento ).

Regards,
Ryan